# How to extract velocity and acceleration from $N$-body simulation data?

Tags: kinematics, data-analysis

I have data from an $N$-body simulation and want to do some data analysis. I would like to extract the velocity and acceleration of each particle. The data consists only of the positions of each particle for different points in time. For a single particle, the data looks as follows

```
step x y
1 0.952 -0.336
2 0.918 -0.333
3 0.925 -0.325
4 0.912 -0.332
```

What is the best approach to extract these quantities from my data?

Comment: Time step is constant?

Comment: @JánLalinský Yes, time step is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use numerical differentiation to obtain velocities and accelerations if this is all that you have. For the numerical methods you also have to decide how to treat the edge points. Finally, to obtain the velocity and acceleration in meaningful units, you also need to know what value and unit $dt$ has and in what unit your position coordinates are.

Here is a small Python code snippet how to calculate the velocity and acceleration based on an array containing positions at equidistant time spacing. The positions are array `x` and would correspond to your x column. `vx` is then the array with the velocities, obtained by applying the numerical derivative as provided by [numpy.gradient](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html), to obtain the correct values you have to divide by the timestep. The acceleration `ax` is obtained in the same way using the velocities as input. In the end, its just the discretized version of the equations
$$
v_x = \frac{dx}{dt}\\
a_x  = \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{dv_x}{dt}
$$

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t, dt = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000, retstep=True)
x = 2*t*np.sin(t)
vx = np.gradient(x)/dt
ax = np.gradient(vx)/dt

fig, (ax0,ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(3,1)
ax0.plot(t,x)
x_abs_max = np.abs(x).max()
ax0.set_ylim(-x_abs_max, x_abs_max)
ax1.plot(t,vx)
vx_abs_max = np.abs(vx).max()
ax1.set_ylim(-vx_abs_max, vx_abs_max)
ax2.plot(t,ax)
ax_abs_max = np.abs(ax).max()
ax2.set_ylim(-ax_abs_max, ax_abs_max)
plt.show()
```

This only works for equidistant data.

Alternatively you could also do an interpolation of your position values and take the derivatives of the obtained interpolation functions. Most interpolation functions provide analytic derivatives and thus "analytic" velocities and accelerations. This approach is more convenient if you need callable functions that provide velocities and accelerations at any value within your boundaries.

Comment: Thanks, that is really helpful! Can you also give me a hint how I correctly take the edge points (the beginning and end of the simulation) into account? When I'm not mistaken, your approach only considers interior points, right?

Comment: This also includes the edge points. You can look up the numpy.gradient documentation that i linked for details. The script that i posted is using first order forward differencing and first order backwards differencing at the edges. You can improve this with the key word edge_order=2 to use second order differencing at the edge points. For example `vx = np.gradient(x, edge_order=2)/dt`.  The central points are always treated with a central second order differencing scheme.